# Проблема с кодировкой виджета

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Подскажите, почему может быть такая проблема с кодировкой при наведении и черные точки?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы не было точек дайте тегу ul: `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: А где?
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,twitter,viber,whatsapp,telegram"

Comment: скорее всего ваши стили переопределяют стили ya-share2, наверняка используется `!important`. Посмотрите код элемента и в вкладке стилей можно отследить какие ваши стили переопределяют.